# OpenWRT dropbear - how to require BOTH key AND password for login?

Tags: openwrt, dropbear

I've just put OpenWRT on a Wi-Fi router I have and I'm setting it up. For reasons beyond my control, I've got a mandate to use multi-factor auth for all admin functions. Unfortunately, from what I've found so far, no one's implemented TOTP or Yubikey support for OpenWRT's logins (tell me if I'm wrong on that point).

In order to be able to hit the mark for this thing, what I'd like to do is set things up so that BOTH an SSH key AND a password are required for login. Note that this needs to be password on the router, NOT just the passphrase on the key itself.

Yes, I am FULLY aware that this doesn't actually increase security any. But it doesn't reduce security, and it meets the standard and keeps me from having to argue with people who have a checklist instead of an understanding.

If this isn't possible with dropbear, is it possible with openssh? I can install that if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell this isn't possible, and the solution was to simply install OpenSSH, disable dropbear, and use the following options in the sshd_config:

```
AuthenticationMethods "publickey,password"
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitRootLogin yes
```

I also arranged things so that the web interface is only available via SSH tunnel.